# How To Organize ItemsPanel Layout?

Tags: wpf

I have the code below which I want to display a series of buttons horizontally with an image and text label, and below that row of buttons one label for the entire button group.  What I currently have displays the buttons in a row, but the group label displays in the same row to the left of the buttons.  I'm probably doing this wrong, but I'm impressed that I got this far.  I've tried putting the Child ItemsPanel in a StackPanel, but then it shows no buttons - it seems to loose contact with the collection from the parent window.  Is there an easy way to connect this collection and organize the label below the buttons?  I'm thinking my next try is to collect the data from the parent in the child's code-behind and build an ItemsSource which I will then connect to the ItemTemplate, but I don't really know how to do that either.

Parent window snippet:

```
<User_Controls:ToolbarGroup GroupLabel="Group 1">
    <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="Test 1"/>
    <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="Test 2"/>
    <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="Test 3"/>
</User_Controls:ToolbarGroup>
```

Child window code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="Fiducia_WPF.User_Controls.ToolbarGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:User_Controls="clr-namespace:Fiducia_WPF.User_Controls" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Loaded="ItemsControl_Loaded"
    d:DesignHeight="170" d:DesignWidth="320">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="170" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="Temp"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <Label Name="lblGroupTitle" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Group X" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" />
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `ControlTemplate` for your ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="Fiducia_WPF.User_Controls.ToolbarGroup" ...>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
                <Label x:Name="lblGroupTitle" Content="Group X" ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="170" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="Temp"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

Setting the Content of the `lblGroupTitle` Label may probably better be done by binding it to a property of the ToolbarGroup control:

```
<Label Content="{Binding GroupTitle,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=User_Controls:ToolbarGroup}}" ... />
```

Comment: Clemens: Thanks for the suggestion.  You may be on the right track, but it's not setting the lblGroupTitle Content when I use the GroupLabel property in UserControl:ToolbarGroup.  First, I had to add </ItemsControl.Template> after </ControlTemplate> to get your code to compile.  Second, I have a GroupLabel property behind the child window and it has a property set function that calls var oLabel = this.Template.FindName("lblGroupTitle", this) as Label; but oLabel is null.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Clemens: Thanks for the reply.  Your suggestion is probably the right answer, but it confuses me.  However, it gave me another idea that works.  I reasoned that when the GroupLabel property is set the lblGroupTitle control doesn't exist yet.  So I store the GroupLabel value in a class property.  I added an event handler to the ItemsControl Loaded event and in that event handler I can find the lblGroupTitle control and set its text to the GroupLabel property.  That's probably not the best way to do it, but it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a straight up Grid:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ... />
 <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ... />
 <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ... />
 <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I know how to do a Grid.  I don't want to do that because this process is going to be repeated about 50 times with different numbers of buttons and different labels.  I also tried putting a grid around the ItemsPanel and that also lost connection to the data from the original call.

Comment: So one item may have 3 buttons and another item only 2? And you want the 3 button row split in 3rds and the 2 button row split in 1/2? Are you going to have multiple labels per row? one say underneath button 1&2 and another under 3? If so, I think you'd have to write a custom layout panel as there is nothing built in that will do that. If I was doing this (if my assumptions are correct) then I would derive a class from Grid and add a few DPs so I can make bindable grid and row definitions. That'd probably be the easiest way unless you want to start from scratch